# Why does the Arbiter scream in Halo 3?

Tags: halo

In Halo 3, after the portal to the ark opens, the Arbiter begins to scream. He also does this right after he killed the Prophet of Truth.

Why does he do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its just a scream of exhilaration. Like those screams people sometimes do when they achieve a difficult challenge and scream their hearts out with triumph...